# In WPF how to use a converter to Grayscale an Image for contacts when its offline

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding, converters

I am making a messenger application in which I am using lync client for this purpose.
In my application UI I am getting the contacts (which is an object of LyncClient having properties like name, image , etc) in a listview and loading them in a data template which is defined as follow:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContactsTemplate">
        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="150" Height="150" Margin="10">
            <Border Background="{StaticResource ListViewItemPlaceholderBackgroundThemeBrush}">
                <Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title}"/>
            </Border>
            <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="{Binding Availability, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToPresenceColor}}" Opacity="0.75">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" Foreground="{StaticResource ListViewItemOverlayForegroundThemeBrush}" Style="{StaticResource TitleTextStyle}" Height="20" Margin="15,0,15,15"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
```

It has an image and textblock which show the image and name of the contact and as its shown below the background of stackpanel is binded to a converter which map the availibility status to a color so that for example the background of stackpanel will turn red when the contact availibility is busy.

now my **question is** how to have the same effect for the image?(making the image gray or red according to presence status)

I am new to binding so totaly lost in this bindig concept.

**My idea was:**
there is a **effect** evend handler for image so i thought of using that for this purpose and use

```
<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title} effect="{Binding Availability, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToPresenceColor}}"/>
```

and inside the converter under some condition I want to use some code in which i need to get the ***image source***, but as we are getting the image source through binding  `<Image Source="{Binding Image}"` I am not able to get the image source in the converter.

please suggest me your ideas.

Comment: Would reducing the Opacity to say 0.5 when not available work for you?

Comment: @kenny,
welll i dnot want to tuch the opacity of the image, just color of image

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a converter. Use a pixel shader, such as this Grayscale effect: http://bursjootech.blogspot.no/2008/06/grayscale-effect-pixel-shader-effect-in.html

Comment: well thanx for reply AkselK, but as i said i want to change the picture color according to user presence status...like when its busy the image should be reddish or when its offline it should be grayish .
**Well**  as u can see in the code 
'<Image Source="{Binding Image}" Stretch="UniformToFill" AutomationProperties.Name="{Binding Title} effect="{Binding Availability, Converter={StaticResource AvailabilityToPresenceColor}}"/>'
I am just binding image which is a** property of Contact object**. I want to send the Availability properties of a Contact object to convert method.

Comment: **Continue**
or i want to bind the image with the whole Contact OBJECT if it is possible...or if some other way please let me know.

Comment: You could do that with multiple DataTriggers. Define two DataTriggers which say something like <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding Availability}" Value="Availiability.Unavailable"><Setter TargetName="shaderEffect" Property="Color" Value="Gray"/></DataTrigger> or something. Given that you have a property Availability in Contact, and that you have extended the Grayscale effect to take a color. I haven't tried that, but somebody has probably done it. Just do try a Google search for wpf color overlay pixel shader or something.